# Preventing UpdatePanel partial postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel, postback

I have an UpdatePanel on a pretty slow page. Its UpdatePanel is set to update conditionally. The problem I'm facing is that the UpdatePanel does a partial postback immediately on being rendered clientside. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to prevent that first partial postback from happening?
2. Is that even good practice? Why or why not?

Thanks for your help.

Markup:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional"  ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server" ID="updatePnlValidationErrors">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <span runat="server" id="validationErrors" class="error"></span>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="Click" ControlID="btnCompletePurchase" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="Checkout_Click" ControlID="checkoutBox" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There is no code directly touching the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Do you update the update panel in your page load event?

Comment: @DTs  No, not on the server-side. I only have two triggers bound to it, and both are on click events on buttons.

Comment: how do you check your update panel to see if it postbacks on page load?

Comment: "The problem I'm facing is that the UpdatePanel does a partial postback immediately on being rendered clientside" - can you post markup and code so we can verify this. Doesn't sound right to me, UpdatePanels shouldn't do that unless you're telling it to update.

Comment: @sh1rts I edited it into the question.

Comment: @AliShahrokhi I put in a breakpoint on the PageLoad handler.

Comment: Are u sure no client-side code like `btnCompletePurchase.click()` is executed (whether directly in client-side or server-side generated) ? Also - how indeed to you know if partial postback happens - you do now that `PageLoad` fires on initial page load as well? Have you checked `IsPostBack` value at your breakpoint?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yup, on the second breakpoint, IsPostBack returns true, and scriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack returns true as well. I'm also sure no click events are fired.

Comment: It appears that 'checkoutBox' is custom control, right? If this is true, can you check that in the Page_Load for this user control, or somewhere else inside this control, that particular event is not fired?

Comment: There are two controls how can trigger the asyc postback. The one is the asp button (if you didn't inherit it in a custom button control ). The second one is your custom control. My guess is, one of these control fires one of their events, which triggers the async postback. I think you should check these control's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

OK, your asyncpostbacktrigger in your code are not pointing to the right controls I guess, you may have eliminated them only for the demo purposes but they are critical for our test. here is my complete simulation of your code and its results at the end.

I have added two **missing** associated controls for your AsyncPostBackTriggers outside your update panel;

> ```
>  <asp:Button ID="btnCompletePurchase" runat="server" Text="Button"
>              OnClick="btnCompletePurchase_Click" />
>  <asp:CheckBox ID="checkoutBox" runat="server" 
>                OnCheckedChanged="checkoutBox_CheckedChanged" />
> ```

and your code will look like the code below:

> ```
>  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
>
>  <asp:Button ID="btnCompletePurchase" runat="server" Text="Button"
>              OnClick="btnCompletePurchase_Click" />
>  <asp:CheckBox ID="checkoutBox" runat="server" 
>                OnCheckedChanged="checkoutBox_CheckedChanged" />
>  <asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional"  ChildrenAsTriggers="false" 
>                   runat="server" ID="updatePnlValidationErrors">
>      <ContentTemplate>
>         <span runat="server" id="validationErrors" class="error"></span>
>      </ContentTemplate>
>      <Triggers>
>         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="Click" 
>                                       ControlID="btnCompletePurchase" />
>         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="CheckedChanged" 
>                                       ControlID="checkoutBox" />
>      </Triggers>
>  </asp:UpdatePanel>
> ```

and here is the break point result on first time Page_Load event:

[image]

so you could copy and paste this code to check the result at your end as well.

Comment: Your point is that in his aspx he forgot to include to controls who trigger the update? That's not possible, because he'll get exception when he tries to open the page.